# How to wrapper PDO Class?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to wrap PDO class to the new class. The problem is after wrapper some method  it can't access other method. in below code. it wraps query to perform try catch and return error. But, after i wrap that query method. i cant call any after PDO method. like fetchAll and other.

```
class aegis{
    private $init, $dsn, $user, $pass;
    private $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
        PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING  
    ];
    private $error = [];

    public function __construct($host, $port, $db_name, $user, $pass){
        $this->dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$db_name;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect(){
        try{
            $this->init = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->options);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            if(isset($e)){
                array_push($this->error, $e->getCode());
                array_push($this->error, $e->getMessage());
                array_push($this->error, time());
            }
        }
    }

    public function query($sqlStatement){
        if(isset($this->init)){
            try{
                $this->init->query($sqlStatement);
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                if(isset($e)){
                    array_push($this->error, $e->getCode());
                    array_push($this->error, $e->getMessage());
                    array_push($this->error, time());
                }else{
                   return $this->init->query($sqlStatement);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function close(){
        $this->init = NULL;
    }

    public function logError(){
        return $this->error;
    }
}

$aegis = new aegis($host, $port, $db_name, $user, $pass);

$rows = $aegis->query("SELECT `market` FROM `result`")->fetchAll();

foreach($rows as $row){
    echo $row.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Because your `query` method doesn't return anything on success. Btw, `if(isset($e))` in the catch is redundant. I don't know of any way it could get there and not be set.

Comment: @Jonnix i think i puts isset there to check. if there's error it will push the error. otherwise, it will return. is it wrong to return query?

Comment: Looking more closely, I have no idea what your catches are doing, but I feel it's a (quite large?) misunderstanding of what try / catch is for and how they work. Perhaps have a look at the documentation, catch blocks don't run if no exception is thrown in the try block. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: yeah, i think i need to learn try catch concept. i think `try` only check.it doesn;t return anything until inside catch wrapper to handle theres thrown error or not. thx

Comment: No that's not how they work. Everything in the try block runs (until an exception occurs), it's not a dry run, it's not a "check if this is okay, then go into a catch. If an exception is thrown inside that try (that hasn't been previously caught) then the the try ends, and the relevant catch code will run. If you end up in the catch block an exception HAS been thrown. If no exception is thrown in the try, then no catch block will run at all. You can do anything inside a try block that you could do outside one, so you can return the query results inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `query()` if the original call succeeds to `$this->init->query` doesn't return anything.  But also if there is an exception and the exception isn't set (which doesn't make sense) then it will re-execute the query and return the result.

```
public function query($sqlStatement){
    if(isset($this->init)){
        try{
            return $this->init->query($sqlStatement);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            array_push($this->error, $e->getCode());
            array_push($this->error, $e->getMessage());
            array_push($this->error, time());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what you want to return if an exception happens, or if you want to re-raise some exception.  But this returns false, which will cause problems with...

```
$rows = $aegis->query("SELECT `market` FROM `result`")->fetchAll();
```

as the `fetchAll()` will fail (it will be trying to call `fetchAll()` on `false`).

Alternative use

```
if ($result = $aegis->query("SELECT `market` FROM `result`") ) {
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();

    // Output data
}
```

Comment: The point my code is i need to minized the code in main code. but, it still reproduce a log. So that information will usefull later for debug. if there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to wrap PDO class to the new class.

In reality, you don't. Your class has so many issues and offers so little that original PDO doesn't that there is really not a single reason to prefer this class over original PDO. Learn how to use PDO first (**prepared statements** specifically) and only then try to create a simple wrapper. Here is an article I wrote based on hundreds similar questions asked here on Stack Overflow, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes), it will help you with your wrapper. But for the moment - again - just use original PDO as is.

Comment: Why i need to wrap cause i need to minimized the code with extra feature return error. each step. from initilization PDO and SQLstatement.

Comment: You don't need it either. Please kindly read about [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). In short, a PDO exception all you really need for error reporting. an exception already contains all the required information, writing a code to move it into array just makes no sense. Just use the exception right away

Comment: Can u give example how to use error built-in without try and catch. so i can minimized the code. and it still report like try and catch?

Comment: It depends on your goal. What you're going to do with this error information?

Comment: I need to get getCode and getMessage from all exception PDO. I need to check if it connect or not and insert into database for information

Comment: Then you are supposed to use a try catch operator.

Comment: thats why i need encasuplation PDO class. cause. i have my production main code. it spam too many try and catch repeat.

Comment: if you spam  too many try and catch then you are doing something wrong. normally there should be not a single try catch. I have no idea why do you need so many